# html-select <option selected=""> doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, html-select

I have 3 html `<select>` the year, month, and day. Both the year and month automatically sets to the current year and current month. I did that purely in PHP. However, the day which is being triggered by Javascript doesn't seem to work even though I already did

```
if (j == <?php echo date('d') ?>)  days_select.options[days_select.options.length] = new Option(j, j, true);
```

The default day is still 1 not the current day. What is even frustrating is that when I checked it on firebug the selected day is the current day... I am a total noob in programming that's why simple things like these are kinda hard for me to grasp. Pls help...

**`date_select.php`**

```
<body onload="loadDays();">
 <script type="text/javascript" >

  function loadDays() {
   var year = parseInt(document.getElementById('years').value);
   var month = document.getElementById('months').value;
   var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
   var days = new Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);

   if ((year % 4) == 0)  days[1] = 29;

   var days_select = document.getElementById('days');
   days_select.options.length = 0;

   for(i in months) {
    if (month == months[i]) {

     for(var j = 1; j <= days[i]; j++ ) {
      if (j == <?php echo date('d') ?>)  days_select.options[days_select.options.length] = new Option(j, j, true);
      else days_select.options[days_select.options.length] = new Option(j, j);
     }
     break;
    }
   }
  }

 </script>

 <span style="display: table; ">
  <span style="display: table-cell; ">
   <select id="years" onchange="loadDays();">
    <?php 
     for($year = 1900; $year <= 2100; $year++ ) {
      if ($year == date('Y')) echo "<option value='$year' selected=''>" . $year . "</option>";
      else echo "<option value='$year'>" . $year . "</option>";
     }
    ?>
   </select>
  </span>
  &nbsp;
  <span style="display: table-cell; ">
   <select id="months" onchange="loadDays();">
    <?php 
     $months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" );

     foreach($months as $month){
      if ($month == date('M')) echo "<option value='$month' selected=''> " . $month . "</option>";
      else echo "<option value='$month'> " . $month . "</option>";
     }
    ?>
   </select>
  </span>
  &nbsp;
  <span style="display: table-cell; ">
   <select id="days" >

   </select>
  </span>
 </span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting this in as a separate answer since it, well, is one.

The third parameter to `Option()` is whether the option is selected by default, as though it were specified in HTML.  The fourth is whether it is actually selected right now.  Add another `true` to your `Option()` call and it works for me in testing.

```
new Option(j, j, true, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because `<?php echo date('d') ?>` produces the string `"04"` with a leading zero.  Your `j` loop counter is an integer, and will never match the string output by PHP.

Try wrapping it in Javascript's `parseInt()` function, or use `date('j')` for no leading zero.

```
if (j == parseInt(<?php echo date('d') ?>))
```

Better yet, just use Javascript's own Date objects to get the current day.

```
var theDateObj = new Date();
var today = theDateObj.getDate(); // Will output int 4 for today.
```

Comment: I see it now - you need another parameter to your `new Option()`. You've set the `defaultSelected` parameter `true`, but you also need the following parameter `true` to say whether it is actually selected right now. `new Option(j, j, true, true);` Tested and working for me with this modification.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to new Option(j, j, true, true) so I can accept the answer.